# Sitecore 9 update 1 xDB Data Migration Tool Pipeline Batch Extremely slow/hangs

Tags: xdb, xconnect, migration

We have Sitecore 9 Update 1 installed successfully. Both of the below services work fine.

- Sitecore xConnect Search Indexer
- Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine

All required databases are installed properly and respective users are configured properly including `collectionuser` for Shard tables. `collectionuser` has membership to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` and has Connect and Execute permissions on the three Shard databases. We have also reindexed, relinked databases and deployed marketing definitions.

We are trying to use xDB Data Migration tool to transfer all analytics information from our existing Mongo database to Sitecore 9 Sql xDB.

When we trigger the pipeline batch to read MongoDb contacts into xConnect, everything works and we can see that the batches are processed properly. At one point, when it has processed all batches, we are expecting the indexer service to process each batch and save data into Sitecore 9 xDB Sql database tables.

The issue is that, this processing is either extremely slow or it just hangs and we are not able to get any pointers from logs to understand what the issue might be. As an example, we run the xDB data migration pipeline batch and after 12 hours, we see just 300 odd records in the `Fact_PageViews` table when the total expected count is close to 40K. I don't find any helpful pointers on Sitecore documentation also.

Could one of you shed light on what we might be missing? We are running against a tight deadline to migrate from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.

Comment: Hi. Can you point xDB Data Migration Tool version?

Comment: We have currently installed the following Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108, MongoDB Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108, Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108, xConnect Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108 and xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108

Comment: What was your "max thread count" to sync contacts?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to access my sitecore environment now since the pipeline batch is in limbo but we did not make any change and are using the default value that was set when we installed the xDB data migration packages.

Comment: If you did not change anything it means it was run in one thread. You could increase procession changing the number of thread. You also can speed up processing if configure resolving. For example set "do not look for existing contacts" if you migrate them first time. All these settings can help you reduse time to migrate all data.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I shall try that out. Is there a max range for the thread count? What is ideal?

Comment: I cannot exactly say the right "max thread count". It depends on your machine. Try 10. :)

Comment: One important thing from documentation. "Do not change the Max Thread Count value on any other pipeline step in the contact migration process. Doing so may prevent interaction data from being migrated properly." It means that you can change the value only in "Iterate MongoDB Contacts and Run Pipelines" and leave as is for everyone else.

Comment: Vlad, we have been trying your suggestions via different combinations of said speed up options. We have noticed that the pipeline batch process is now fast but the part where data gets aggregated back to SQL is extremely slow, like ~600 records in Fact_PageViews table in the last more than 15 hours. Not sure what is going on. Still investigating. Any pointers?

Comment: I think aggregation is not a part of xDB Data Migration Tool. It means to migrate contacts properly, the tool migrates mongo data through the xConnect. For example if 100 contacts where migrated but agregated only 50 that is issue of xConnect. But I could be wrong here. Sorry.

Comment: Just noticed that in the log the call to "INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Request:  http://sc91.sc/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/...." happens only if I am logged into Sitecore... So maybe at some point, this is failing to authenticate and hence the part where it tries to aggregate and save the data is not working since I am logged out. Is there a way to force Sitecore to be logged in indefinitely without timing out?

Comment: Thereare aggregation settings Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config

Comment: It's kind of unrealted to xDB Processing.. but EXM uses threads too, and the default value is 10 threads.. which is SUPER low. My advice is to watch the CPU of the Processing server.. if it's idle to not being used.. keep upping your thread count until you see it utilizing 60,70,80 percent of the CPU

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if my answer will be full however it may help. If you are going to migrate a huge number of contacts and its interactions via xDB Data Migration Tool you need to know how to configure migration properly before run it.

There are several things that can speed up migration.

1. Max Thread Count (default: 1)
2. Minimum Batch Size (default: 100)
3. Page Size (default: 200)
4. Max Request Length (default: 1048576)
5. Resolve Object Settings
6. ...

---

Here is some points.

**1. Max Thread Count**

*Enabling Multiple Threads*

> By increasing the number of threads
>   used during the migration process you can increase performance, especially when a large number of contacts
>   need to be migrated.
>
> *Navigate to Pipelines > MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration Pipelines > Read Contacts from
>   MongoDB Pipeline > Iterate MongoDB Contacts and Run Pipelines*
>
> **Important.**
>
> Do not change the Max Thread Count value on any other pipeline step in
>   the contact migration process. Doing so may prevent interaction data
>   from being migrated properly

---

**2. Minimum Batch Size**

*Changing Batch Size*

> In order to interact with the xConnect collection service as efficiently as possible, the contact migration
>   process only submits data to the xConnect collection service after a certain amount of data is collection.
>   This threshold can be configured on the contact migration process.
>
> **Note.**
>
> The unit this threshold is measure in an operation. An operation
>   represents a single instruction for the xConnect collection service.
>   Controlling the batch size means specifing the minimum number of
>   operations that must be available before those operations are
>   submitted to the xConnect collection service.
>
> Navigate *to Pipelines > MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration Pipelines > Read
>   Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline > Add xConnect Client to Context*

---

**3. Page Size**

*Changing Page Size*

> Number of objects read from mongo per one page.

---

**4. Max Request Length**

*Set Maximum Request Size on xConnect Server*

> By default, IIS limits the amount of data that can be accepted by the
>   web server. This default setting reduces the effects of certain types
>   of denial-of-service attacks.
>
> This setting is configured in the HTTP
>   runtime settings section in web.config. The property is
>   maxRequestLength:

[image]

> It is recommended that this value be increased to the maximum value 2147483647 while the migration process
>   is running.
>
> **Note**
>
> Do not forget to reset this value after the migration process is
>   finished running.

---

**5. Resolve Object Settings**

*Changing Resolve Object settings*

> That is very impotent to know, before changing these values you should understand and analyze the data you want to migrate. For example, do you need to look for existing object or not. Turning the setting on means send an additional request. Set these values carefully.

[image]

---

**6. ...**

> I believe there are others things that involve on performance.

---

*Read more here*

[Installation Guide](https://doc.sitecore.net/xDB%20Data%20Migration%20Tool/~/media/B8C0A5C3D5874B81A1838CE7E52A5716.ashx)

Comment: A late reply @Vlad but I was trying out a few things before coming back to you. From the look of it xDB data migration seems to be quick and fine especially after making the configuration changes you suggested above. I now am at a point where I feel that it is the xconnect processing that is extremely slow. Once xDB Data Migration tool has pulled all the batches from Mongo, the xconnect processing engine should go in, aggregate them into SQL. But processing is painfully slow (e.g in 15 hours, ***I see 466 rows in [dbo].[Fact_PageViews] table where infact I expect 42K rows***. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NavneetPisharodi Hi, You can play with configuration settings in Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config
At least you can increase default value for "minimumBatchSize" of "contactWorkDispatcher"

Answer (score 2):

One thing that people tend not to read is about the indexes in the MongoDB collection. After creating those indexes the xDB migration is nearly as fast as lightning.

Copy/paste from "xDB Data Migration Tool Installation Guide 2.0.1.pdf"

**1.2.3 Add Indexes to MongoDB Collections**

xDB Data Migration Tool reads virtually all of the data in the MongoDB data for analytics from Sitecore 8.x. In order to do this efficiently, a couple of indexes must be added. Note Adding these indexes is optional. However, if you choose not to add these indexes, you should expect the data migration process to take longer to complete.

1. Open a mongo shell.
2. Select the database with the xDB data you plan to migrate to Sitecore 9.
3. Enter the following commands: 
   db.getCollection('Devices').createIndex({LastKnownContactId:1})
   db.getCollection('Interactions').createIndex({ContactId:1})

Answer (score 1):

Eventually with help from Sitecore support, I figured out what was causing performance degradation. For anyone having the same issue, try making the below config change.

> [Your sitecore instance]\App_Config\Sitecore\DeviceDetection.Client\Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config update **DeviceDetection.Enabled to false**

Why I had to do this is still something I am trying to figure out but at least it got me successfully through the data migration part.

Also, the solution mentioned below did not work for me.

> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/828414

Answer (score 0):

Going to add this for others who find themselves here, as there can be numerous reasons for a slow process. Mine was particularly Mongo related.

First, in addition to [Alex Von Wolferen's Answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/13139/5248), the following index is helpful.

`db.Outcomes.createIndex({"InteractionId": 1})`

Second, be sure that your MongoDB server has the following set in accord with the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/). The `-l` flag was particularly important for these types of full database scans.

-f (file size): unlimited
-t (cpu time): unlimited
-v (virtual memory): unlimited [2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/)
-l (locked-in-memory size): unlimited
-n (open files): 64000
-m (memory size): unlimited [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/)
-u (processes/threads): 64000

This literally took me from 0 entities submitted in 50 minutes to 5000 a minute.

Comment: thanks @AlexMayle for enhancing the information.